Подскажите как создать простые тесты для проверки функций программы написанной на с# winforms
Как создать простые тесты для проверки функций программы написана на с# winforms состоящий из обработчиков событий.
вот сделал класс в него поместил метод
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KURSOVAIACALCULATOR
{
    public class ClassScore
    {
        public double first_num;
        public char user_action;
        public string result_lab;
        public string result_lab2;

        public ClassScore(double first_num, char user_action, string result_lab, string result_lab2)
        {
            this.first_num = first_num;
            this.user_action = user_action;
            this.result_lab = result_lab;
            this.result_lab2 = result_lab2;
        }

        public void Score()
        {
            double second = Convert.ToDouble(this.result_lab);
            double res = 0;
            this.result_lab2 += Convert.ToString(second) + "=";

            switch (this.user_action)
            {
                case '+': res = this.first_num + second; break;
                case '-': res = this.first_num - second; break;
                case '*': res = this.first_num * second; break;
                case '%': res = this.first_num * second / 100; break;
                case '/':
                    if (second != 0)
                    {
                        res = this.first_num / second;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.result_lab2 = "";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            this.result_lab = Convert.ToString(res);
        }
    }
}

Вот код unit теста  выдает ошибку Тестирование  Длительность    Признаки    Сообщение об ошибке
Test1 Не выполнено  System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly
подскажите что
using NUnit.Framework;
using KURSOVAIACALCULATOR;

namespace TestScoreClass
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private ClassScore score;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Инициализация экземпляра класса ClassScore
            this.score = new ClassScore(5, '+', "3", "");
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Вызов метода Score
            this.score.Score();

            // Проверка результата
            Assert.AreEqual("8", this.score.result_lab);
        }
    }
}


Так а где тут winforms?
